# コメントが消えた？

Tags: サポート, コメント

コメントをつけた質問をあとから確認しようとコメントを確認したところコメントが削除されておりました。
どうしてコメントが消えてしまったのでしょうか？
他の人がコメントを削除できるのでしょうか？
特に削除されるような内容だったとは思えないのですがどうしてコメントが消えたかが分かりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

該当コメントがされていたのは [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53418/3060) の質問についていたもので、削除を行ったのは私になります。
ただしコメント自体に何か(重大な)問題があったわけではありません。

コメント機能は「[質問や回答を明確にするための一時的なメモや付箋](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)」という扱いになっています。
今回のケースであれば「質問は後からでも編集ができるので、もう少し詳しく説明してください」というコメントに対して、質問者自身が追記を行っていたので、「意図は伝わってコメントの役割は終えた」と判断して削除させてもらいました。

コメントはやり取りが繰り返され量が多くなってくると、後から見た時にどの情報が本当に必要なのかが分かりづらくなってきますので、古くなった・役目を終えた情報は整理する場合があります。

ただし今回はコメントを付けてからあまり間を置かずに削除してしまったので、「何か問題があったんじゃないか」と不安や誤解を与えてしまったかもしれません。今後はより慎重に対応するようにします。

Comment: お気に入り(☆)があるのは知っていますが修正したあとのアフターフォローのために行動履歴から私はコメントを追ったりしています。ヘルプにはコメントを削除しなければいけない明確なルールの記載は無いように思えます。また、マイナス票も該当の質問にはついており、改善するためのアドバイスの経緯が他の人にも分かる工夫が必要に思えました。ともすると気に入らない、不必要だと感じたコメントを削除にかかる行為にもなると思うので破壊的なアクションは控えていただいた方がいいのでは？と感じました。……とはいえどうして消えたのかについては承知いたしました。

Comment: 私も「コメントした後のフォロー」をしたいところですが、コメントが消えているため、“自分の行動履歴”から辿れなくなっています。

Comment: こういうとき修正だとリビジョンとか残りますが、削除履歴か何かって残ったりしないものなんですかね？「該当のコメントは削除されました」とか出て質問が出るとか……

Comment: コメント削除を含めたすべての履歴は `https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/timeline` から見ることができます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 権限の問題で削除の履歴は見れないようです。

Comment: @Sieg さん、すいません、コメント削除履歴はモデレーター限定機能でした。 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301456/341401